# How I should approach this regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following code to try and get some html between two tags. So far I have this:

```
$pattern = "/<span style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;font-size:12px'>(.*?)<\/span>/s";

preg_match($pattern, $html, $episodes);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($episodes);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

this is the sample data that is getting fed into the $html variable

```
<span style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;font-size:12px">

<b><span style='font-size:18px'>The Walking Dead</span></b><br><br><br><br><b>1x01 - <a style='text-decoration:underline;color:#ffffcc;font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;' href='/?12&tv=1'>Days Gone Bye</a></b><br><br>

</span>
```

I'm just trying to get that block of html out. Any ideas why the pattern isn't matching?

Comment: dont parse html with regular expressions

Comment: To expand, you should use a DOM Parser. I personally like this one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `DomDocumnet` class when working with the DOM

Something like this *untested* snippet should work

```
$html = "<span style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-family: verdana,geneva,sans-serif;font-size:12px'>My text is here</span>";
$document = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$span = $document->getElementByTagName('span');
echo $span->item(0)->nodeValue;
```